# How to insert unicode string to mysql

Tags: python, mysql

the code is like below:

Connect server

```
MySQLdb.connect(host=ip, user='root', passwd='root',db='test',use_unicode=True,charset="utf8")
......
sql = "INSERT INTO ci(id,name) VALUES (493,u'Hello')"
print sql
ret = root.execute(sql)
.....
```

In the server, the tyoe of name is VARCHAR(1000). Then when i run this script, it shows error `ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near`

But when i replace u'Hello' with 'Hello', it is OK. So maybe it doesn't support unicode,then i insert unicode string such as "你好" to the table by GUI manually, it is also OK. I can not find what is the reason, who can help me

Comment: Well you're sending the notation `u'Hello'` to MySQL, but that's python notation. MySQL will accept unicode, but you need to find their notation for it and get Python to send it in that form.

Comment: @Gijs  how can i get the notation of MYSQL?

Answer (score 3):

MySQL needs strings to be enclosed in straight quotes: '你好', 'u' symbol is not allowed. Just declare the whole string as Unicode and pass it to MySQL. Here I am using a prepared statement:

```
sql = u"INSERT INTO ci(id,name) VALUES (493,'你好')"
```

Don't forget to run "SET NAMES 'UTF-8'" (or UTF-16 - don't know, what encoding you are using) after you connect to MySQL to ensure, that the server will correctly interpret the string you send it.

Comment: better on this manner: `sql = u"INSERT INTO ci(id,name) VALUES (493, ?)"; ret = root.execute(sql, ['你好'])`. It allow avoid problems related whith different data types

Comment: @MichaelKazarian Yes, prepared statements are better. Shouldn't it be [u'你好']?

Comment: I show right way. I can't test it because I don't use your locale.